# Canvas. Изображение загружается без расширения

Tags: javascript, canvas

Имеется код для работы с canvas и вывода текста на изображении

```
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            const imageObj = new Image();

            canvas.id = "canvas";
            canvas.width = 1080;
            canvas.height = 1920;

            document.querySelector('#sertificate').appendChild(canvas);

            imageObj.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
                ctx.font = "30px Optima Cyr";
                ctx.fillText(data.first_name_1, 320, 790);
                ctx.fillText(data.first_name_2, 620, 790);
                ctx.fillText(data.last_name_1, 320, 880);
                ctx.fillText(data.last_name_2, 620, 880);
            };
            imageObj.src = "../img/@2x/sertificate.jpg";
```

До этого момента все работает прекрасно, далее я создаю кнопку, при нажатии на которую должна скачиваться картинка

```
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.classList.add('button');
            button.innerHTML = 'Скачать';
            document.querySelector('#sertificate').appendChild(button);

            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                link.download = 'sertificate.png';
                link.style.display = 'none';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
            });
```

При нажатии на кнопку, начинается скачивание, но файл не имеет расширения. А при попытке скачать, браузер выдает ошибку сети. Подскажите, как исправить это
[image: скачивается файл без расширения]

Comment: Возможно проблема в том что переменная canvas и её id называется одинаково. Я бы попробовал поменять и проверить например так: сверху canvas.id = "mycanvas"; снизу link.href = mycanvas.toDataURL('image/png');

Comment: @Александр-Лабчук, успешно выполнил Ваш код просто скопировав его. Как результат получил изображение с нанесённым текстом сохранённое в файле sertificate.png 
Возможно мешают какие-то расширения браузера, установленные у вас или настройки брандмауэра/фаервола/антивируса

Comment: Странно, но когда я поменял canvas.height с 1920 на 920, то все стало работать, я не понимаю ничего